# iOS OTA App- I can download it but no one else can?

Tags: ios

I am distributing an app OTA using Ad-Hoc (NOT enterprise) for my class, and when they try to get it on their devices, it tells them it can't download. It starts loading, but once it gets to installing, it fails. Do I need to get my classmates UDIDs? I've seen things like GBA4iOS that you can just download it from the website without any UDID or anything, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To distribute Ad-hoc all UDID's must be added to the distribution profile which you sign your app with. You are limited to 100 per year. Non UDID options include enterprise distribution, Apple's TestFlight service, and Jailbreaking. Apple provides details on the available distribution options [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html).

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks! I'll accept your answer in about 10 mins.